# Lua pattern to validate a DNS address

Tags: regex, lua, dns, lua-patterns

I am currently using this regular expression to loosely validate a DNS address:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*$
```

Which would match things like `hello.com`, `hello`, and `hello.com.com.com`. I was trying to replicate it exactly as it is into a Lua pattern. I came up with the following Lua pattern:

```
^([%d%a_]+(%.[%d%a_]+)*)$
```

So that I can use the following code to validate the DNS address:

```
local s = "hello.com"
print(s:match("^([%d%a_]+(%.[%d%a_]+)*)$"))
```

For some reason this always fails, although it looks like a 1:1 copy of the regular expression.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry to inform you that Lua patterns are not regular expressions. You cannot translate the `^[A-Za-z0-9_]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*$` to `^([%d%a_]+(%.[%d%a_]+)*)$`, because you cannot apply quantifiers to groups in Lua. Grouping is only used for capturing in Lua.

Comment: Yu Hao, this post is related to both Lua patterns and regular expressions. One should know both to answer this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lua patterns are not regular expressions. You cannot translate the `^[A-Za-z0-9_]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*$` to `^([%d%a_]+(%.[%d%a_]+)*)$`, because you cannot apply quantifiers to groups in Lua (see [*Limitations of Lua patterns*](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial)).

Judging by the `^[A-Za-z0-9_]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*$` regex, the rules are:

- String can consist of one or more alphanumeric or underscore or dot characters
- String cannot start with a dot
- String cannot end with a dot
- String cannot contain 2 consecutive dots

You can use the  following work-around:

```
function pattern_checker(v)
    return string.match(v, '^[%d%a_.]+$') ~= nil and -- check if the string only contains digits/letters/_/., one or more
           string.sub(v, 0, 1) ~= '.' and            -- check if the first char is not '.'
           string.sub(v, -1) ~= '.' and              -- check if the last char is not '.'
           string.find(v, '%.%.') == nil             -- check if there are 2 consecutive dots in the string
end
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vE3cO8):

```
-- good examples
print(pattern_checker("hello.com")) -- true
print(pattern_checker("hello")) -- true
print(pattern_checker("hello.com.com.com")) -- true
-- bad examples
print(pattern_checker("hello.com.")) -- false
print(pattern_checker(".hello")) -- false
print(pattern_checker("hello..com.com.com")) -- false
print(pattern_checker("%hello.com.com.com")) -- false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the pattern to `^[%w_][%w_%.]+[%w_]$`, although that still allows for double dots. When using that pattern while checking for double dots, you end up with this:

```
function pattern_checker(v)
    -- Using double "not" because we like booleans, no?
    return not v:find("..",1,true) and not not v:match("^[%w_][%w_%.]+[%w_]$")
end
```

I used the same testcode as `Wiktor Stribiżew` *(since it's good testcode)* and it produces the same results. Mine is also 2 to 3 times faster, if that matters. *(Doesn't mean I don't like Wiktor's code, his code also works. He also has a link to the limitations page, a nice touch to his answer)*

*(I like playing with string patterns in Lua)*

Comment: This approach is good but not equivalent to the original expression. The point is that this pattern will require at least 3 characters in the input string. The original regex pattern can match 1-character strings.

Comment: Sadly enough, this is probably the closest you can get to that pattern. Using this pattern _(after emiting '^' and '$')_ you could actually match domains in a text, as long you check for double dots afterwards.